# Word Code Directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

Change the Directory of the code below.

.SaveAs FileName:='Test' & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF,   AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .Close SaveChanges:=False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like `FileName:="C:\My Documents\" & Test & ".pdf"` where `Test` is a variable of String type.